# Restore preference after it removing

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

In `PreferenceActivity` I get the `Preference` `myPref` by calling `myPref = findPreference(..)` after that I check for some condition and remove it from "PreferenceList" like this : `getPreferenceScreen().removePreference(myPref);` in second call of my method I need to add that `Preference` again but `findPreference(..)` returns `null`.How do I restore that `myPref` for adding it later to the "PreferenceList" by calling `getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(myPref);` ?

```
Preference myPref= findPreference( getString( R.string.path_preference ));//return null after removing

        if (condition) {
            if (!pbePathPreferenceRemoved) {
                getPreferenceScreen().removePreference(myPref);
                pbePathPreferenceRemoved = true;
            }
        } else if (pbePathPreferenceRemoved) {
            getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(myPref);
            pbePathPreferenceRemoved = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to make the `Preference myPref` member of my `PreferenceActivity class` and initialize it only once in `onCreate(..)` method, after that I can remove it and add again.